# Is it possible in Fortran to determine if two polymorphic objects are the same derived type?

Tags: filter, fortran, polymorphism, derived-types

Is it possible to take two polymorphic objects and determine if they are of the same derived type (or class)? The intention is to use it as a clean way to filter a generic linked list.

Something like the following mock code.

```
function isSameType(a, b) result(itIs)

    !arguments
    class(*), intent(in) :: a
    class(*), intent(in) :: b

    !output
    logical :: itIs

    !return true if a and b are both the same type
    !return false if a and b are not

end function isSameType
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "same derived type"? I guess, though, that `same_type_as(a,b)` is simply what you want.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. I could not get it to come up in a google search, and my "Modern Fortran Explained" book apparently decided to list it in the  "Object-Oriented Programming" chapter rather than the "Intrinsic Procedures and Modules" chapter. If you make than an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard inquiry function `same_type_as` tests equality of *dynamic* type of two objects:

```
program typetest
  implicit none

  type t1
  end type t1

  type t2
  end type t2

  class(*), allocatable :: a, b

  allocate(t1 :: a)
  allocate(t2 :: b)

  print *, SAME_TYPE_AS(a,b)   ! False
end program
```

`same_type_as` does not test *declared* type (except where this is the same thing). It does not consider kind parameters:

```
program partest
  implicit none

  type :: t1(n)
     integer, kind :: n
  end type t1

  type(t1(1)) :: a
  type(t1(2)) :: b

  print *, SAME_TYPE_AS(a,b)   ! True
end program
```

Further, to get a useful result you'll be wanting (at least) one of `a` and `b` to be of extensible dynamic type.  While you can ask

```
program intrinsictest

  implicit none

  class(*), allocatable :: a, b

  allocate(real :: a)
  allocate(double precision :: b)

  print *, SAME_TYPE_AS(a,b)  ! ...
end program
```

the result is processor dependent (could be true or false).