# how to get type name in Fortran

Tags: fortran

How can I get a unique name of a variable type in Fortran? An ideal case is shown below:

for the case

```
real::a
type(some)::x
```

I want to implement some function `f(x)` so that

```
f(a) = "real"
f(x) = "some"
```

The return value of `f` need not be a string, other cases, a unique integer for instance, is OK. Is such a built-in function exist?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I don't think something like this can exist, because my understanding is that the compiler needs to know at compile time which type each variable is supposed to be. But I've been wrong in the past.

Comment: Nothing like that exists. You can create your own generic function with some limits.

Comment: I hesitate to ask ... but why do you "need" this?  What programming requirement would this capability satisfy?  There is just a wee chance that the requirement could be satisfied by another mechanism, possibly even one built in to Fortran.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Quite. I'm wondering if somebody is trying to recreate `same_type_as`. And even if that is what they are trying to do I still want to know what they really want.

Comment: Even with `same_type_as`, @IanBush, we don't have enough information to knowt that would be useful, given how it's [not really to be used with intrinsic types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324326/3157076).

Comment: As in the other comments, you can't do this (built-in), but it's not clear why you need to. `real :: a` gives something you know to be a real, so you don't need to ask a function what it is. There are cases where (`class(*), intent(in) :: x)`, etc.) you don't know the type, but a `f(x)` returning the type doesn't help in most cases. Please give much more detail on what you want to do with the result so we can indicate a good approach.

Comment: @francescalus Agreed but that is not what I am saying - I have a suspicion that somebody is not aware of `same_type_as` and is trying to recreate the functionality. The above would be one route.

Comment: @IanBush, yep, I agree with your sentiment in the comment - I just didn't want someone to look at `same_type(a,1.)` thinking it works, job done.

Comment: I am yet to see a good use case for `same_type_as`. Also, I think it would be unnecessarily hard to compare strings in particular.

Answer (score 3):

No, such capability does not exist in Fortran. Some programming languages do have this (e.g. C++, it has almost anything someone can invent and some more https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name but do note the disclaimers about uniqueness and mangling).

You can make a generic function for some limited set of types yourself

```
interface type_name
  procedure type_name_real
  procedure type_name_some
end interface

function type_name_real(o) result(res)
  character(:), allocatable :: res
  real, intent(in) :: o
  res = "real"
end function

function type_name_some(o) result(res)
  character(:), allocatable :: res
  type(some), intent(in) :: o
  res = "some"
end function
```

This obviously concerns the declared type and non-polymorphic entities. But your question did not show any polymorphism.